# Problem with creating object from API data

Tags: javascript

I've fetched data from PokeAPI, and now I'm struggling with creating an object containing this data. Data looks like this:

```js
valueObject = {
  "stats": [{
      "base_stat": 45,
      "effort": 0,
      "stat": {
        "name": "speed",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
      }
    },
    {
      "base_stat": 65,
      "effort": 0,
      "stat": {
        "name": "special-defense",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

I wanted to create a function, that returns object with max value of base stat from all API calls (there is an array of data for each Pokemon). Object should look like this:

```js
obj = {
  speed: maxvalue of base.stat,
  special - defense: max of base.stat,
  ...
}
```

Firstly I made separate assignment to every stat:

```js
valueObject["speed"] = Math.max(...data.map(item => item.stats[0].base_stat));
// data is an array of all fetches
```

But I feel it can be done in one line, or one for loop. Unfortunately, I can't do that and I'm getting errors all the time. I tried mapping and using for loop:

```js
// Option 1//
for (let i of data[0].stats) {
    valueObject[data[0].stats[i].stat.name] = Math.max(
      ...data.map(item => item.stats[i].base_stat)
    );
  }
//Option 2 (it seems a bit off)//
  valueObject[data[0].stats.map(item => item.stat.name)] = Math.max(
    ...data.map(item => item.stats.map(i => i.base_stat))
  );

//I'm using data[0] to just get property names from any pokemon
```

So, can you help me figure it out?

EDIT: @mplungjan Ok I edited my post, but it doesn't seem to run anyway and I don't know why.

```js
const maxStatsValues = data => {
  //data array is passed as argument, but its elements look like this:
  data[0] = {
    "stats": [{
        "base_stat": 45,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
          "name": "speed",
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
        }
      },
      {
        "base_stat": 65,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
          "name": "special-defense",
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
  data[1] = {
    "stats": [{
        "base_stat": 72,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
          "name": "speed",
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
        }
      },
      {
        "base_stat": 90,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
          "name": "special-defense",
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
  let obj = {};
  data[0].stats.forEach(x => {
    obj[x.stat.name] = Math.max(obj[x.stat.name] | 0, x.base_stat)
  })
  console.log(obj);
  //my code: 
  // let valueObject = {};
  //   for (let i of data[0].stats) {
  //    valueObject[data[0].stats[i].stat.name] = Math.max(
  //      ...data.map(item => item.stats[i].base_stat)
  //    );
  //  }
  // return valueObject;

  return (obj);
};
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56150352/edit) again and then post a snippet of a runnable script with input and show us expected output

Comment: For that kind of operations, `array.reduce` is probably the most suitable method.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry but I don't know how. How can I make this runnable, if data array is fetched from API?

Comment: You already have example data. Add the JS to that data in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
valueObject = data.flatMap(x=>x.stats);
valueObject.forEach(x => {
  obj[x.stat.name] = Math.max(obj[x.stat.name] | 0, x.base_stat)
})
```

```js
let data = [];
data[0] = {
  "stats": [{
      "base_stat": 45,
      "effort": 0,
      "stat": {
        "name": "speed",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
      }
    },
    {
      "base_stat": 65,
      "effort": 0,
      "stat": {
        "name": "special-defense",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
      }
    },
  ]
}
data[1] = {
  "stats": [{
      "base_stat": 72,
      "effort": 0,
      "stat": {
        "name": "speed",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
      }
    },
    {
      "base_stat": 90,
      "effort": 0,
      "stat": {
        "name": "special-defense",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
      }
    },
  ]
}

let obj = {};
valueObject = data.flatMap(x=>x.stats);
valueObject.forEach(x => {
  obj[x.stat.name] = Math.max(obj[x.stat.name] | 0, x.base_stat)
})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What does | mean? I don't think I've seen it before.

Comment: this is bit "or" - we use it here in case when value  in obj is undefined - numer|0 = number (not change number), undefined|0 = 0 (return zero) e.g. type in console `5|0` and `undefined|0`

Comment: Ah right. I didn't see this operator in JS yet. And what is obj now?

Comment: Well I changed valueObject to data[0] because I'm passing data array as argument into the function. It created an object with proper names, but values are incorrect. 
attack: 49
defense: 49
hp: 45
special-attack: 65
special-defense: 65
speed: 45
Max values are about 200 for each. They are also strangely repeated twice.

Comment: Ok I added whole function at the bottom of original question